# Is the exponential of the trace convex?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, exponential-function, trace

Take $a \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $B,X \in \mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ where $B=B^T$ and $X = X^T$, $a$ and $B$ are fixed.

Is then the function
$$f(X) =  ae^{\operatorname{tr}(BX)}$$ convex in X?

For $d=1$ this is definitely the case, but the introduction of the trace is what confounds me.

Comment: no need for any formulas; a convex function of an affine function is convex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, because if $X_1,X_2\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ and $t\in[0,1]$, then\begin{align}f\bigl(tX_1+(1-t)X_2\bigr)&=\exp\bigl(\operatorname{tr}\bigl(B.(tX_1+(1-t)X_2)\bigr)\bigr)\\&=\exp\bigl(\operatorname{tr}\bigl(tBX_1+(1-t)BX_2\bigr)\bigr)\\&=\exp\bigl(t\operatorname{tr}\bigl(BX_1\bigr)+(1-t)\operatorname{tr}\bigl(BX_2\bigr)\bigr)\\&\leqslant t\exp\bigl(\operatorname{tr}\bigl(BX_1\bigr)\bigr)+(1-t)\exp\bigl(\operatorname{tr}\bigl(BX_2\bigr)\bigr)\\&=tf(X_1)+(1-t)f(X_2).\end{align}

Comment: My apologies in advance... Just out of curiosity, the inequality you have invoked on the 4th row, is this some well-known? Jensen's inequality? If Jensen's inequality, then does it not assume that the function is convex/concave (so kind of chicken or egg-like problem)?  or one could also show that the $f^{\prime\prime}(X) > 0$ for the convexity, right?

Comment: @user550103 I just used the fact that $\exp$ is convex.

Comment: Thanks! I had sort of convinced myself of this because the trace is affine, but it's good to see it in a few lines.

Comment: @NeedsToKnowMoreMaths I'm glad I could help.